# Powershell to output folder based on content lastwritetime

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to create a powershell script that will look into the contents of a folder for the lasttimewrite on a file, or any file and output the folder and the time stamp. Using to idenrify profiles in a terminal server environment with raoming profiles, but folders lastwrite time is for the folder itself whereas each time a user logs in something inside is touched and timestamped.

I've attempt the following

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).addDays(-1)} |  Foreach-Object { $_.Directory } | sort-object name -descending | export-csv c:\lists.csv
```

I've tried a couple iterations this seems to work

```
get-childitem -recurse | where-object {$_.name -eq "Pending"} |
where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).addDays(-1)} | 
where-object {$_.PSIsContainer} |
foreach {$_.Parent} | foreach {$_.name}
```

the only issue is now for the output putting the lastwritetime from the "Pending" folder displayed

Comment: Are you trying to get files or folders? Please elaborate.

Comment: I just want the folder name, basically to identify which users have touched their profile in whatever number of days.

but say its user1, user2, user3 the folder lastwritetime isn't updated as it isn't modified, but the contents inside say a user.dat file has a timestamp that I could use to say its lastwritetime is within a day, so I want to check every folders <userfolder>/user.dat for its lastwritetime and from that display the <userfolder> name and user.dat lastwritetime

Comment: get-childitem -recurse | where-object {$_.name -eq 'Pending'} |
    where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).addDays(-1)} | 
    where-object {-not $_.PSIsContainer} |
    Foreach-Object { $_.Parent }

Comment: So you want to print pairs of folder name and the modified time of the most recently modified file inside this directory. Right?

Comment: yes I want to print the folder name and the modified time of the most recent file inside the directory, but I have a specifc file that I can check against, or in my example the folder pending

I'd like the output to say

userfolder1 7/17/13...
userfolder3 7/16/13...

based on the criteria of the folder (or a specific file) having a lastwritetime greater than a definted period

what I'm struggling with is not usign recurse to make it not run for ever rather maybe useing a variable

    $path = get-childitem | foreach {$_.name}

Comment: if it coudl just look in the userfolder and I can specify the file or folder to look at the lastwrite time then store the last write time as a vairbale and output the parent of the file/folder which would be the userfolder and the file/folder lastwritetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $path = get-childitem | foreach {$_.name}
 $directory = $path | foreach {$_+"/"}
 get-childitem -path $directory | where-object {$_.name -eq "Pending"} |
 where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt "12/30/2012"} | 
 where-object {$_.PSIsContainer} |
 foreach {$_.parent.name + "," + $_.lastwritetime} > 
 c:\users\opr9823\2013users.csv
```

this did it for me

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure, if I got your question right, but my little script shows all items, who have been changed in the last day and the time of change + the directory:

```
$directories = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\test -Directory).FullName
     $directories | foreach  {if (($_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).adddays(-1)) -or ((get-childitem -path $_ -Recurse).lastwritetime -gt (get-date).adddays(-1))) {
         $itemname = (Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Recurse | where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-1)}).BaseName
         $itemtime = (Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Recurse | where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-1)}).LastWriteTime
         $_ >> C:\timestamp.txt; $itemname >> C:\timestamp.txt; $itemtime >> C:\timestamp.txt;
                                                                                                                                                                  }
                             }
```

I got this back from my little script:

```
C:\test\DIR - Copy (2)
test (2)
test
test2 (2)
test2

Wednesday, 17. July 2013 17:49:43
Wednesday, 17. July 2013 17:49:43
Wednesday, 17. July 2013 17:49:43
Wednesday, 17. July 2013 17:49:43
```

I don't know how many files you have to check, so I can't say if this will be fast.

EDIT:

```
$path = C:\test
gci $PATH | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1
```

Shows me this:

```
Directory: C:\test


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                                    
 ----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                                    
 d----        18.07.2013     09:37            Neuer Ordner - Kopie (2)
```

Comment: I just want to check a specific file or folder within a folder for a gt timestamp and return the folder name if it meets that requirement

Comment: updated my answere. Simple transaction to select the most recent file. is that what you wanted?